# passing variable to php using ajax post

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

I know they are so many posts for the same reason I am looking for.

My prob is I have done all the things to populate row values on a dialog box (Jquery) with accordion & Ajax.

I have below code to first get the click function and open the dialog box, now I interested in populating values  values in accordion wise so for these first I need to pass the variable from the row so that I can call my DB to rest of the magic. I know I can directly do it on the Jquery but I am comfortable with HTML form with dynamic nature.

Please help me

## Js Code

```
$('#example tbody').on('click','tr', function () { var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

var oData = oTable.fnGetData(this); $.ajax({
        url: "main.php",
        type: "POST",       dataType:"json",
        data: { oData : oData} });  $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
          heightStyle: "content",
          active: 0,        collapsible: true }); $( "#accordion-resizer" ).resizable({

  resize: function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh");   } });    var $dialog = $("#server")
                   .dialog({
                       //title: data1+'*****'+node,
                        autoOpen: false,
                        resizable: true,
                        height: 627,
                        hide: "puff",
                        width: 700,
                        show: { effect: 'slide'},
                        modal: true,
                        draggable: true,
                        buttons: { 
                        'Close': function() {
                           $dialog.dialog('close');
                        }
                       }
                   });  $dialog.dialog('open');  });
```

## PHP/HTML Code

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $data = json_decode($_POST['oData'], true);
print_r($data);
?>
 <div id="server" title="My Tenant" style="display: none;">
    <div id="tenant_info">
         <div id="accordion-resizer" class="ui-widget-content">
  <div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
      <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
      <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
      <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
      <ul>
        <li>List item one</li>
        <li>List item two</li>
        <li>List item three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>
      <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain what help do you need?

Comment: my query is simple, I just want to pass this value's'var oData = oTable.fnGetData(this);' to the PHP so that I can construct a form for the clicked row.